# Preview an image on a popup Window before Upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, preview, image-upload

I am able to display all the form fields on a popup Window except the image. The image gets displayed directly on the form. It should also be displayed on the popup Window along with the other fields before submission.

```
function openPreview()
{
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var msg= document.ElementByClassName("nicEdit-main")[0].innerHTML;
var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
var oFReader= new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
var popWin=window.open(title, 'Preview_Entry');
popWin.document.write('Title:' + title + '<br /> Message:' + msg + '<br /> Category: ' + category + '<br /> Status:' + status + oFReader);
}
```

Comment: You are setting `src` of an image on main window. Instead you should create an image tag on popup window and set it's `src`

Comment: i created a var and wrote it in popWin.document.write. but i am facing an issue with displaying it.     popWin.document.write('Title: ' + title + '<br /> Message: ' + msg + '<br /> Category: ' + category + '<br /> Status: ' + status  +  imgUrl );

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the last line should give you the desired output

```
var oFReader= new FileReader();
var imgUrl;
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
imgUrl=oFREvent.target.result;
 };
var popWin=window.open(title, 'Preview_Entry');
popWin.document.write('Title:' + title + '<br /> Message:' + msg + '<br />     Category: ' + category + '<br /> Status:' + status + '<br />' +"<img src='" + imgUrl + "' /> );
```

Comment: i think u forgot to close it. so i edited as + '<img src=" ' + imgUrl + ' " />' );        But it is still displaying an error on the popUp Window!

Comment: whats the error that you get? Can you please post it?

Comment: i see this in the popup window. but the image is being displayed on my form!                               HTTP Status 404 - /MobileAppProj/Title

Comment: You will need to pass your base URL to the popup window.window.open("Your base URL", title, 'Preview_Entry'). If this works please mark my answer as answer

Comment: i tried inserting my base URL but it is opening the main page on my popup Window

Comment: You can add your base url  to image url then imgURL= baseURL + oFREvent.target.result;

Comment: so for example: `var oFReader= new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
var imgUrl= baseURL + oFREvent.target.result;
 };
var popWin=window.open(title, 'Preview_Entry');
popWin.document.write('Title:' + title + '<br /> Message:' + msg + '<br />     Category: ' + category + '<br /> Status:' + status + '<br />'+ '<img src=" ' + imgUrl + ' " />' ); `

Comment: Yes, and make sure you declare and assign baseURL

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the pop up once the image data is loaded. So that you can set the preview image src accordingly. Try this:

```
var oFReader= new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL( document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
  var popWin=window.open('about:blank', 'Preview_Entry');
  popWin.document.write('Title:' + title +
    '<br /> Message:' + msg + 
    '<br />     Category: ' + category + 
    '<br /> Status:' + status + 
    '<br />' +
    '<img src="' + oFREvent.target.result + '" /> ');
  popWin.document.close();
};
```

Comment: i tried this method but nothing happens when i click on my Preview button! No Window is popped up as well. and why did your remove this line: document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;

Comment: `document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result; ` will display the image in your main window / form .. I suppose you didn't want it. And this code is working on my local machine. If popup is not opening then probably there is some error while loading the image. What error are you getting in console?

Comment: yes correct. i dont want the image to be displayed on the form but on the popup Window instead. i am not getting any error on my console. Just that Nothing is executed when i press on my preview button.